# SED Multiple search items

Tags: sed

SED question

I need to print any lines that have contain 11 for November or 12 for December.

My two questions are:

1. How do I search for more than one item I.E. print lines with the value 11 and 12?
2. How do I tell the search to look in column 4 which has the dates?

What I have so far:

```
sed -n -e '/11/,/12/p' datebook
```

File `datebook`:

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700
Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92086:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Ephram Hardy:293-259-5395:235 CarltonLane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:56700
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:268500
Lesley Kirstin:408-456-1234:4 Harvard Square, Boston, MA 02133:4/22/62:52600
William Kopf:846-836-2837:6937 Ware Road, Milton, PA 93756:9/21/46:43500
Sir Lancelot:837-835-8257:474 Camelot Boulevard, Bath, WY 28356:5/13/69:24500
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Zippy Pinhead:834-823-8319:2356 Bizarro Ave., Farmount, IL 84357:1/1/67:89500
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:126000
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:22350
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:95600
Tommy Savage:408-724-0140:1222 Oxbow Court, Sunnyvale, CA 94087:5/19/66:34200
Yukio Takeshida:387-827-1095:13 Uno Lane, Ashville, NC 23556:7/1/29:57000
Vinh Tranh:438-910-7449:8235 Maple Street, Wilmington, VM 29085:9/23/63:68900
```

Comment: This site is international: it would be as well to state that the dates occurring in column 4 are in the US-style month/day/year format.  I also see that people were snoozing through the Y2K crisis; there really isn't a good reason not to store all 4 digits of the year.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145402/regex-alternation-or-operator-foobar-in-gnu-or-bsd-sed

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell the search to look in **column 4** which has the dates?

This is an indication that you should use `awk` because `sed` doesn't have the concept of fields. An `awk` solution would be

```
awk -v FS=":" '$4 ~ /^1[12]\/.*/{print}' datebook
```

**Output**

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:268500
```

**Deciphering the solution**

- `FS=":"` sets the the field/column delimiter to colon.
- `$4` represents the column four in your input file which is the date in the format `mm/dd/yy`
- The `~` in `$4 ~ /^1[12]\/.*/` means we do a regex match in which

  - `^` represents the beginning of the string
  - `[12]` can match either one or two.
  - Since the regex part itself is delimited by `/` you need to escape any literal `/` as in `\/`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to select lines where the first characters after the third colon on the line are `11/` or `12/` (since the data formats appear to be pre-Y2K-style US-format dates with `mm/dd/yy` notation).  So you write:

```
$ sed -n '/^\([^:]*:\)\{3\}1[12]\//p' datebook
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:268500
$
```

The `^` matches at the start of a line; the `\([^:]*]:\)` part looks for a series of zero or more non-colons followed by a colon; the `\{3\}` requires 3 of them; the `1[12]\/` demands `11/` or `12/` after that; the `p` prints.

I observe that the initial statement says 'contain 11 for November or 12 for December', but your first numbered question says 'value 11 and 12'.  These are contradictory; a given date field can only start with one *or* the other, not both.  I've assumed that 'or' is what you intended.

Comment: Yes, or is what I meant.  This worked perfect..   Thanks for explanation behind it as well.